# shallow learning OpenBLAS warning -->cant model

Tags: python-3.x, random-forest, openblas

I am trying to model using XGboost and an RF (separately and the code is terminating before the model is output.)

I get the following error:

```
OpenBLAS warning: precompiled NUM_THREADS exceeded, adding auxiliary array for thread metadata.

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```